# Best way ever to find the value in a HTML file?

Tags: html, parsing, find

hello.

I need help to find a token value in a HTML file.

```html
    </div>
    <div class="nota"><input type="checkbox" id="desactivarComentario" name="desactivarComentario" /><label for="desactivarComentario">No deseo cargar comentarios para los informes. (modificable en <a href="/net/configuracion" target="_self">Configuración</a>)</label></div>    
</div>

<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="XyPDNNtKIHJVg2xhyikMyUcwD26-T9z8HMEWiQh0KXq2vUjMahh2n-nL_fh6_bPJUupSiWc3fcvCdcz-ohZB-4K34WT0-PRXX-MsltnQI8mSYg81kzrFhvByJtLl36D-0" />


<div id="wrapper-resultado" class="cf ly-body">
    <div class="cf barra-consulta">
        <ul class="left">
            <li class="fst">
```

In this case the value that i should obtain is: 
"XyPDNNtKIHJVg2xhyikMyUcwD26-T9z8HMEWiQh0KXq2vUjMahh2n-nL_fh6_bPJUupSiWc3fcvCdcz-ohZB-4K34WT0-PRXX-MsltnQI8mSYg81kzrFhvByJtLl36D-0"

What is the best ever method to find it?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.. Can you please add more details like you want to obtain the value on click of something? or it should be visible on checkbox check?

Answer (score 1):

You could use jQuery and execute:

```
var val = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]).val();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
var x = document.getElementsByName("__RequestVerificationToken")[0].value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this vía jQuery, see the code below:

https://jsfiddle.net/monodisco/hj7p8dne/6/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var __RequestVerificationToken = $("input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]").val();

    alert("__RequestVerificationToken IS ::: " + __RequestVerificationToken);
});
```